# keys for scroll up/down

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

What keys perform scroll up/down on the Windows 7 Explorer preview pane?

Or, (since the above gives "This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.")...

The complete description of my problem is that I would like to know the keys that perform scroll up/down on the Windows 7 Explorer preview pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up-arrow and Down-arrow work for me. More precisely, they move the selected item up or down,
scrolling the display as needed.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder why the comment I made here upon accepting this answer is no longer showing.

Comment: OK, so I'll repost. I was looking for keys that would work while focus in on the file list. The PDF preview pane doesn't show a focus indicator. Up/Down Arrow work ... once I have moused to the pane. I've asked a new Q for how to get there with keys http://superuser.com/questions/872787/how-to-select-and-scroll-preview-up-down-using-keys-not-mouse .