# How to select and scroll preview up/down using keys, not mouse?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm using Windows 7 and Explorer.

If I select a PDF and press ALT+P to show the preview pane, how then using keys may I scroll up/down? E.g. key to the pane and then use up/down arrow.

Note: keys, not mouse.

Comment: That'll be up to the PDF preview provider to implement. Which PDF program are you using?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat is the only PDF viewer installed, so my knowledge. I see nothing on the preview pane that IDs the provider. Perhaps this helps: http://i.imgur.com/NFQdeHE.png . I'd be surprised if the key to get to the preview pane is provided by the preview provider, but regardless I'd be glad to know it. Thanks.